# Como corrigir um Bug com carregamento de um Fragment dentro de outro Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Eu tenho um MainActivity com Navigation Drawer, e todos os itens deste navegador abre em Fragments. Ao iniciar o aplicativo eu carrego a página inicial da seguinte forma:

```
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.ftMainPages, new Fragment01Home());
        ft.commit();
```

E dentro dessa pagina inicial eu tenho um outro navegador com tabs, que também trabalha com fragments dentro dele.

Ao iniciar ele carrega tudo corretamente, mas quando eu seleciono um item do navigation drawer saindo da pagina inicial, e depois retorno a esta página, as tabs ficam desconfiguradas. Onde só ao clicar na terceira aba que eu tenho a pagina inicial de volta.

Fica um pouco complicado em explicar com palavras, mas eu fiz um screen recorder, e postei nesse link demonstrando o problema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl2O6.jpg

Segue abaixo a minha classe MainActivity (PagesHome.Class) do navigation drawer, e a classe da pagina inicial que trabalha com as as tabs (Fragment01Home.Class).

**PagesHome.Class**

```
public class PagesHome extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private static SharedPreferencesUtils SPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pageshome);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //Abrir Fragment Inicial (Home)
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.ftMainPages, new Fragment01Home());
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        int backstack = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }  else if (backstack > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        } else {
            ExitDialog();
        }
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pages_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityPesquisa.class));
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityConfiguracoes.class));
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
            ExitDialog();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            ft.replace(R.id.ftMainPages, new Fragment01Home());
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_favorites) {
            ft.replace(R.id.ftMainPages, new FragmentFavoritos());
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_controlpanel) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityControlPanel.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contato) {
            ft.replace(R.id.ftMainPages, new FragmentContato());
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_faq) {
            ft.replace(R.id.ftMainPages, new FragmentFAQ());
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sobreita) {
            ft.replace(R.id.ftMainPages, new FragmentSobre());
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_privacy) {
            ft.replace(R.id.ftMainPages, new FragmentTerms());
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
            LoginDialog();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_deslogar) {
            DeslogarDialog();
            return true;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

**Fragment01Home.Class**

```
public class Fragment01Home extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Fragment01Home";

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Titulo da página
        ((PagesHome)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Teste");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsviewhome);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabshomeitens);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       return view;
    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentNegocios(), "Teste1");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentNoticias(), "Teste2");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentCompras(), "Teste3");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentEventos(), "Teste4");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentEmpregos(), "Teste5");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }
    }

}
```

Alguém poderia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado, e como solucionar este problema?

Comment: tenta usar getSupportFragmentManager() no lugar de getFragmentManager() e vice versa

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @IgorOliveira, mas sabe me dizer o porque da mudança e diferença entre os dois? Vou dar uma pesquisada tbm. Valew

Comment: Testei aqui @IgorOliveira, e não deu certo. Na verdade ficou ainda pior. Agora ele da o mesmo bugs só que com todas as abas, até as que antes não dava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os fragments sobem como Bean, para evitar que seja criado uma nova instancia vc pode fazer isso, deve ajudar no controle de memoria. Inserir dentro do fragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(false);
    }
```

Agora a possivel solução do seu bug deve ser aqui

```
mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Vc deve chamar `getChildFragmentManager()` para que o adapter do viewpager gerencie os novos fragmentos, assim quando o fragmento pai for removido ou deletado da memoria, os demais fragmentos afiliados vão junto

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado, ajudou d+++

Comment: De nada, boa sorte com o projeto

Comment: Obrigado, pra ti tbm nos seus, abraços